# how to work with nested json object in c#

Tags: c#, json, .net

api return json which is nested and i dont know to retrieve data from it and map it to my model. i want to retrieve the data from nested but not sure how to do this with index and value. Thanks in Advance.

```
   public class MikesExcelModel
    {
        //public int id;
        //public object AuthorizingManagerId;
        public string Name;
        //public DateTime UpdateDate;
        public string Phone;
        public string Email;
    }




    public class MikesExcelResults
    {
        public List<MikesExcelModel> value = new List<MikesExcelModel>();
    }


    public List<MikesExcelModel> GetExcel()
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            addToken(client);
            var result = client.GetAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/ucfdev.sharepoint.com,4c319763-130d-4ee1-bc1f-72543da0a847,8a2f59f4-9d56-4aec-be21-33d0347293d1/drives/b!Y5cxTA0T4U68H3JUPaCoR_RZL4pWnexKviEz0DRyk9HjXtfo70gjRbH706GdwO5m/items/01HA4SXKSESD3RW3UYPNCZ2OHQAEWWDTKH/workbook/worksheets('sheet1')/tables(%27%7B079215E2-A6D7-4CC2-AB1E-9AC38F36D1CC%7D%27)/rows").Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseContent = result.Content;

                // by calling .Result you are synchronously reading the result
                string responseString = responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                JavaScriptSerializer serialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
               // dynamic apiResult = serialiser.DeserializeObject(responseString);
  
                 return Utilities.DeserializeObject<MikesExcelResults>(result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result).value;
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("Couldn't get excel datas.");

        }
    }

}
```

Data return by api looks like this:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#sites('ucfdev.sharepoint.com%2C4c319763-130d-4ee1-bc1f-72543da0a847%2C8a2f59f4-9d56-4aec-be21-33d0347293d1')/drives('b%21Y5cxTA0T4U68H3JUPaCoR_RZL4pWnexKviEz0DRyk9HjXtfo70gjRbH706GdwO5m')/items('01HA4SXKSESD3RW3UYPNCZ2OHQAEWWDTKH')/workbook/worksheets('sheet1')/tables('%7B079215E2-A6D7-4CC2-AB1E-9AC38F36D1CC%7D')/rows",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.id": "/sites('ucfdev.sharepoint.com%2C4c319763-130d-4ee1-bc1f-72543da0a847%2C8a2f59f4-9d56-4aec-be21-33d0347293d1')/drives('b%21Y5cxTA0T4U68H3JUPaCoR_RZL4pWnexKviEz0DRyk9HjXtfo70gjRbH706GdwO5m')/items('01HA4SXKSESD3RW3UYPNCZ2OHQAEWWDTKH')/workbook/worksheets(%27%7B00000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000%7D%27)/tables(%27%7B079215E2-A6D7-4CC2-AB1E-9AC38F36D1CC%7D%27)/rows/itemAt(index=0)",
            "index": 0,
            "values": [
                [
                    "Mike Callahan",
                    "407-266-1431",
                    "MTC@ucf.edu"
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "@odata.id": "/sites('ucfdev.sharepoint.com%2C4c319763-130d-4ee1-bc1f-72543da0a847%2C8a2f59f4-9d56-4aec-be21-33d0347293d1')/drives('b%21Y5cxTA0T4U68H3JUPaCoR_RZL4pWnexKviEz0DRyk9HjXtfo70gjRbH706GdwO5m')/items('01HA4SXKSESD3RW3UYPNCZ2OHQAEWWDTKH')/workbook/worksheets(%27%7B00000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000%7D%27)/tables(%27%7B079215E2-A6D7-4CC2-AB1E-9AC38F36D1CC%7D%27)/rows/itemAt(index=1)",
            "index": 1,
            "values": [
                [
                    "Michael Callahan",
                    "407-823-3455",
                    "mtcallah@ucf.edu"
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "@odata.id": "/sites('ucfdev.sharepoint.com%2C4c319763-130d-4ee1-bc1f-72543da0a847%2C8a2f59f4-9d56-4aec-be21-33d0347293d1')/drives('b%21Y5cxTA0T4U68H3JUPaCoR_RZL4pWnexKviEz0DRyk9HjXtfo70gjRbH706GdwO5m')/items('01HA4SXKSESD3RW3UYPNCZ2OHQAEWWDTKH')/workbook/worksheets(%27%7B00000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000%7D%27)/tables(%27%7B079215E2-A6D7-4CC2-AB1E-9AC38F36D1CC%7D%27)/rows/itemAt(index=2)",
            "index": 2,
            "values": [
                [
                    "cvcfcv",
                    "zVCCvc",
                    "cvvvvb"
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Looks like `MikesExcelModel` should just have `int index` and `List<string> values` fields. It's unclear how the other fields `Name` `Phone` and `Email` should be mapped, certainly the serializer has no idea

Answer (score 0):

Maybe traditional way to extract JSON data with `Newtonsoft.Json` library.

1. Convert `jsonData` to `JObject` (via `JObject.Parse`).
2. Get first-level `value`.
3. Get second-level `values`.
4. Flatten second-level `values`.

From

```
[[["Mike Callahan", "407-266-1431", "MTC@ucf.edu"], ...]]
```

To

```
[["Mike Callahan", "407-266-1431", "MTC@ucf.edu"], ...]
```

5. Convert `flattenChildrenValues` to `List<MikesExcelModel>`.
6. Add `List<MikesExcelModel>` to `results.value`

```cs
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
```

```cs
var jsonData = @"{
            ""@odata.context"": ""https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#sites('ucfdev.sharepoint.com%2C4c319763-130d-4ee1-bc1f-72543da0a847%2C8a2f59f4-9d56-4aec-be21-33d0347293d1')/drives('b%21Y5cxTA0T4U68H3JUPaCoR_RZL4pWnexKviEz0DRyk9HjXtfo70gjRbH706GdwO5m')/items('01HA4SXKSESD3RW3UYPNCZ2OHQAEWWDTKH')/workbook/worksheets('sheet1')/tables('%7B079215E2-A6D7-4CC2-AB1E-9AC38F36D1CC%7D')/rows"",
            ""value"": [
                {
                    ""@odata.id"": ""/sites('ucfdev.sharepoint.com%2C4c319763-130d-4ee1-bc1f-72543da0a847%2C8a2f59f4-9d56-4aec-be21-33d0347293d1')/drives('b%21Y5cxTA0T4U68H3JUPaCoR_RZL4pWnexKviEz0DRyk9HjXtfo70gjRbH706GdwO5m')/items('01HA4SXKSESD3RW3UYPNCZ2OHQAEWWDTKH')/workbook/worksheets(%27%7B00000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000%7D%27)/tables(%27%7B079215E2-A6D7-4CC2-AB1E-9AC38F36D1CC%7D%27)/rows/itemAt(index=0)"",
                    ""index"": 0,
                    ""values"": [
                        [
                            ""Mike Callahan"",
                            ""407-266-1431"",
                            ""MTC@ucf.edu""
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    ""@odata.id"": ""/sites('ucfdev.sharepoint.com%2C4c319763-130d-4ee1-bc1f-72543da0a847%2C8a2f59f4-9d56-4aec-be21-33d0347293d1')/drives('b%21Y5cxTA0T4U68H3JUPaCoR_RZL4pWnexKviEz0DRyk9HjXtfo70gjRbH706GdwO5m')/items('01HA4SXKSESD3RW3UYPNCZ2OHQAEWWDTKH')/workbook/worksheets(%27%7B00000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000%7D%27)/tables(%27%7B079215E2-A6D7-4CC2-AB1E-9AC38F36D1CC%7D%27)/rows/itemAt(index=1)"",
                    ""index"": 1,
                    ""values"": [
                        [
                            ""Michael Callahan"",
                            ""407-823-3455"",
                            ""mtcallah@ucf.edu""
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                {
                    ""@odata.id"": ""/sites('ucfdev.sharepoint.com%2C4c319763-130d-4ee1-bc1f-72543da0a847%2C8a2f59f4-9d56-4aec-be21-33d0347293d1')/drives('b%21Y5cxTA0T4U68H3JUPaCoR_RZL4pWnexKviEz0DRyk9HjXtfo70gjRbH706GdwO5m')/items('01HA4SXKSESD3RW3UYPNCZ2OHQAEWWDTKH')/workbook/worksheets(%27%7B00000000-0001-0000-0000-000000000000%7D%27)/tables(%27%7B079215E2-A6D7-4CC2-AB1E-9AC38F36D1CC%7D%27)/rows/itemAt(index=2)"",
                    ""index"": 2,
                    ""values"": [
                        [
                            ""cvcfcv"",
                            ""zVCCvc"",
                            ""cvvvvb""
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }";
        
var jsonObj = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
// Get first-level value
JArray jsonValue = jsonObj["value"] as JArray;

// Get second-level values
var childrenValues = jsonValue.Children<JObject>()["values"];
        
// Flatten second-level values
var flattenChildrenValues = childrenValues.Values<JArray>() as IEnumerable<JArray>;

// Read flattenChildrenValues to List<MikesExcelModel>
List<MikesExcelModel> excelModels = flattenChildrenValues
    .Select(x => new MikesExcelModel
                {
                    Name = x[0].ToString(),
                    Phone = x[1].ToString(),
                    Email = x[2].ToString()
                })
    .ToList();
        
// Add List<MikesExcelModel> to results.value
MikesExcelResults results = new MikesExcelResults();
results.value.AddRange(excelModels);
                
foreach (var model in results.value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Name: {0}, Phone: {1}, Email: {2}", model.Name, model.Phone, model.Email));    
}
```

[Sample program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/C10FhC)